# Body field of some nodes not displayed in teaser view

Tags: 6, nodes

Some of my nodes have an empty teaser field so when I visit a taxonomy page, you cannot see any of the body content. Only when you click on the node title to view the full node can you see the body. Why does this happen? I fix this by manually editing my database and adding content to the teaser field of the node_revisions table but it's troublesome to fix nodes this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a wysiwyg problem or a problem with Drupal teasers counting HTML in the summary character count.

http://drupal.org/node/221257

http://drupal.org/node/823380

Comment: errrm, that was what I answered

Comment: Ya, but those links have patches that work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be related to the WYSIWYG editor you're using. Some of them output a lot of redundant code, so you don't get anything or a bunch of white space before content on teasers. Try using the 'Edit summary feature' that comes with Drupal corer to fine-tune teasers (or you could always have a new teaser text field). Most of the WYSIWYG editors come with a Teaser button, so you should use that.

Comment: I'm using ckeditor so this may be the problem

Comment: Press the 'Source Code' button in CKEditor and check your source HTML, I bet you see a lot of redundant stuff. There you can confirm that's the problem. You can solve it in a number of different ways, like configuring the tags and inline styles the WYSIWYG outputs, or as I said before use a teaser field of the 'summary' core feature.